# python Trie Question: How this iteration runs? (Probably related to shallow copy and assign value)

Tags: python

The code is OK!! I just do not fully understand the code and have question on code itself....Exactly, I noted them with ?????????????? below. Thank you!

```
lst = ['ab', 'ac']
Trie = {}
 
for i in lst:
    cur_node = Trie
    # print("Trie", Trie)
    print("i", i)
    for x in i[:-1]: 
        print("x", x)
        if x not in cur_node:
            cur_node[x] = {} 
            print("1",cur_node)
        print("pre", cur_node)
        cur_node = cur_node[x]
        print("2",cur_node)
    cur_node[i[-1]] = '$' 
    print("last", cur_node)
print(Trie)
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
i ab
x a
1 {'a': {}}
pre {'a': {}}
2 {}
last {'b': '$'}??????????????????????????????????
 
 
i ac
x a
pre {'a': {'b': '$'}}!!??From the above "last", where comes the **'a':** ????
2 {'b': '$'}
last {'b': '$', 'c': '$'}
{'a': {'b': '$', 'c': '$'}}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

This code is to achieve TRIE structure. The question is, I do not know why, from the first iteration to the second iteration, the original cur_node is
last {'b': '$'}
But in the second iteration, the cur_node becomes:
pre {'a': {'b': '$'}}。。。
Is any property of Python I do not know? Could any clever friend tell me why this happen? Thank you!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDPFJ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question with your expected vs actual output. Currently, it is not clear what the problem is, as we don't know what you expected instead. Also, it would be much better if you used meaningful variable names and explicit debug messages.

Comment: Frankly, I can not read the code....I even not sure where to ask because maybe I do not know some key information....of python's dict? assign value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The name `cur_node` starts out pointing to the same object as the name
`Trie`. Remember that [Python variables are names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) for underlying objects (or values); two
names can point to the same object.

```
cur_node = Trie
```

(2) That object is altered:

```
cur_node[x] = {}
```

(3) The name `cur_node` is then attached to the inner object. The outer
object is still sitting around doing whatever (and the `Trie` name still
points to it).

```
cur_node = cur_node[x]
```

(4) That inner object is altered:

```
cur_node[i[-1]] = '$'
```

(5) Loop starts fresh and the name `cur_node` is attached
to the outer object.

```
cur_node = Trie
```